# Fixing problems on a site that only breaks on IE7

Tags: html, css, drupal, internet-explorer-7

I did a new Drupal theme for my site based on the Zen theme. Since I am on Windows 7, I did testing with IE8, Firefox 3.5, and the most recent version of Chrome. The site looks great in all of those, but I just found out that it breaks on IE7. Unfortunately there is no way to put IE7 on Windows 7, so I'm at a loss for how I am going to find the exact cause and test a fix without flagging down a friend with IE7 on Vista or older.

My hope is that someone here might see what the issue is and point it out as something obvious. My HTML and CSS fu is not strong.

The site in question and some specific pages:
http://byswarm.com/
http://byswarm.com/setting-concept/mejijpunk
http://byswarm.com/page/plan

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any way you can combine that css?  On a refresh, each of those included stylesheets is a round-trip...plus in this case, makes it a PITA to debug.  See here for reasoning: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#CombineExternalCSS

Comment: There is an option in Drupal to tell it to compile all the CSS together to reduce the number of scripts sent. I'm reading up to make sure there aren't any gotchyas on that before I enable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Microsoft Virtual PC. you can get IE6, IE7, IE8 VPC image free for development.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Use Sun VirtualBox (freeware) to create Virtual Comps with Windows XP (for IE7) and Windows 2000 or 2003 (for IE6), also recommend to install additionally IEDevTools (tools like Firebug for Firefox) for these IEs...
For fast previewing pages in IE you can use IETester (support 5,6,7,8 versions of IE)

Answer (score 0):

Normally IE8 has a button right to the address bar where you can display it rendered by IE7. If not, you can always try this header, that forces IE8 to render as IE7:

Comment: let's repost that!

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /

(of course with < and >)